# Create Maven Project Fails in Eclipse with a java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I cannot seem to create a Maven Project in Eclipse

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I cannot find any reference to this issue anywhere else, so I am hoping someone has a solution as it is very strange.

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Eclipse Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1) - Vanilla Download

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Have you also encountered the following error: Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE?  If you find a solution, please share it.  Thanks.

Comment: Could this be an issue of restricted privileges?  I'm on a work computer with very limited access.

Comment: @jeffkempf sadly I never did resolve it. My hypothesis was that because my machine was set up to replicate the disk to the corporate network, that was somehow getting in the way. My IT support guys could not work it out though.

Comment: @jeffkempf I was local admin on the machine so I don't think it was that.